# DJI A3 battery problem and waypoint flight in simulator

Tags: dji-sdk

I have set up a DJI A3 controller like in this video : 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=niGGsosi4a4 (however only one compass)

The problem is, when i open the dashboard in DJI Assitant Ver 2.0.0, I see that it says battery low. Why?  It is powered by an external power source.

With that in mind - i am trying to launch the official waypoint sample as shown in the github page : https://github.com/dji-sdk/Onboard-SDK/tree/3.7/sample/linux/flight-control

The rotors turn half a turn, then I receive :  `L824 motors off`

This it says : `Takeoff failed. Aircraft is still on the ground, but the motors are spinning.`

Firmware version is 1.7.5

Previously the battery was 80%; but there was a firmware update requested. so updated the firmware, and this happens.

I checked it with DJI Go app in my mobile device. I can see this time the numbers changing, i.e. height etc - but the DJI GO app in a samsung galaxy 5 does not show the image of a drone in the simulator screen.

Help please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the newest firmware doesn't support your external power source.I suggest you using DJI battery like TB47D,because the api of dji sdk just can read the information of DJI batteries.What's more,for A3,the voltage need to be higher than 21.7V.

Comment: thank you downgrading the firmware solved the problem!! I literally couldnt guess that! Thanks again